# awk to print lines between mth and nth ocurrence of record separator

Tags: awk

I have a .sdf file with the following format:

```
$$$$

> <NAME_OF_FIELDA>
valueA
> <NAME_OF_FIELDB>
valueB
.
.
.
> <NAME_OF_FIELDZ>
valueZ

$$$$

> <NAME_OF_FIELDA>
valueA
> <NAME_OF_FIELDB>
valueB
.
.
.
> <NAME_OF_FIELDZ>
valueZ

$$$$
```

[Each name of field and value are in separate lines. The same pattern is repeated until the end of the file]

Each block between the "$$$$" characters contains information regarding a specific item.

I want to create an awk script (can only use awk) in order to print all the information corresponding to an specific item by selecting the lines between "mth" and "nth" occurrence of the string "$$$$".

For example, to be able to print the lines corresponding to the third item, which is located between the 3rd and 4th occurrence of the "$$$$".

So far I have tried setting the RS and using flags, but I am not being successful.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. 2 points here, 1st- Please do EDIT your question with wrapping samples in CODE TAGS, 2nd- Please do add your efforts in your question.

Comment: Note that `RS` *separates* records. In your input, record number 1 appears before the first instance of `$$$$` and is an empty string.

Comment: If you get rid of all the `...`s in your sample input and add expected output so we have something we can test a potential solution using and add what you've tried so far THEN we can really start trying to help you. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v min=3 -v max=4 'BEGIN {RS="[$]{4}"} NR<=max && NR>=min+1 { print }' file
```

Set the record separator to $ * 4 {4} in the begin block. We then compare the passed in min and max variables to the record number and print accordingly.

Comment: Note that although `gawk` and `mawk` allow RS to be a pattern, according to the standard "If RS contains more than one character, the results are unspecified."

Comment: @WilliamPursell right-ish but it's not unspecified, a POSIX awk uses the first character of a multi-char RS. Per [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html): `RS
    The first character of the string value of RS shall be the input record separator;...`